# Blazor Wasm - How to update base components from an inherited component?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm app with two components:

BaseComp.razor:

```
<h1>I'm base - @Text</h1>

@code{
    protected string Text {get; set;} = "Default";
}
```

ChildComponent.razor

```
@inherits BaseComp

<BaseComp/>

<h1>Hello, only child text!</h1>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = "new";
    }
}
```

and on the page the following will be displayed:

```
I'm base - Default
Hello, only child text!
```

How could I update the `Text` property of the baseComponent from the childComponent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this piece of code

```
@inherits BaseComp
<BaseComp/>  @* a new instance, not inheritance *@
```

You inherit from ***and*** compose with BaseComp. You are not using the inheritance part.

So use only composition and follow the answer from @MarvinKlein but remove the `@inherits` line.
Or change the code to:

```
@inherits BaseComp

@*<BaseComp />*@
@{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }

<h1>Hello, only child text!</h1>
```

Comment: I want to use the base component to render the same grid on all pages but some additional logic. @MarvinKlein 's solution and yours work, are there any downfalls when using the BuildRenderTree method?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use the base component to render the same grid on all pages but some additional logic.

A type of templating for which the current `ComponentBase` wasn't designed.

You can either:

1. Use a different base component that designed to do it.
2. Make it work with `ComponentBase`.

This is how to make it work with ComponentBase as describing how to build a different component is beyond the scope of an SO answer.

Our Wrapper Component:

```cs
<h3 class="text-primary m-2 p-2">Wrapper</h3>
<div class="bg-primary text-white m-2 p-2">
@this.Body
</div>

@code {
    protected abstract RenderFragment? Body { get; }
}
```

And the code-behind file to make it abstract.

```cs
public abstract partial class Wrapper { }
```

Our new `Index`.  The key here is our content no longer goes in the top block - the section the Razor compiler complies into `BuildRenderTree`. Instead we define it in a separate `RenderFragment`.

Our top block now contains the `RenderFragment` property `this.Body` to which we've assigned the base class's `BuildRenderTree` method containing the compiled code from the Template.

```cs
@page "/"
@inherits Wrapper

@this.Content

@code {
    // Where we put the base Template class Render Fragment
    private RenderFragment Content;

    // Ctor - must call base and then we load the base Template class content
    public Index() : base()
        => this.Content = (builder) => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);

    // Our content that the Razor compiler will build in Body
    // __builder is the built in Razor compiler RenderTreeBuilder 
    protected override RenderFragment Body => (__builder) =>
    {
        <PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <div>Welcome to your new app.</div>

        <SurveyPrompt Title = "How is Blazor working for you?" />
    };
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: To prevent confusion, I renamed it to `Wrapper`.  It's just a demonstration to show how you can do it with a bit of code trickery.  It's definitely not fool proof.  I use the technique, but with a very different Wrapper component.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare it as a parameter and pass the value down.

BaseComp.razor:

```
<h1>I'm base - @Text</h1>

@code{
   [Parameter] public string Text {get; set;} = "Default";
}
```

ChildComponent.razor

```
<BaseComp Text="Text"/>

<h1>Hello, only child text!</h1>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Text = "new";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works when I define a property on the childComponent which will be passed to the baseComponent, but is there another way to achieve that? For multiple parameters this could get pretty verbose because I need to define the same properties on both base and child

Comment: Unfortunately not. The common way to do this is by creating a custom class which holds your properties and pass this instance down.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes you are right. I removed it.